# React can not read property ' name of a var ' undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching data from NYTimes API.
This code is showing me the error **can not read property q undefined**

This is the index.js file of my react app. Here tried to access the property of q from this.state.

How can I solve this error and what causes this error?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import $ from "jquery";
import SearchComponent from "./components/Search_component";
import ListViewComponent from "./components/Listview_component";

const api_key = "my api key here";
let url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            q: "usa",
        };
    }
    url = url + "?" + $.param({ api_key, q: this.state.q });
    news = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET"
    })
        .done(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .fail(err => {
            throw err;
        });

    do_search(keyword) {
        console.log(keyword);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchComponent
                    searchkeyword={keyword => {
                        this.do_search(keyword);
                    }}
                />
                <ListViewComponent data={DATA} /> // I have deleted const DATA to reduce pasted code in SO.
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Besides your problem: You should not use jQuery inside of a react app! For doing ajax request, I would recommend axios: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: What @LaurenzGlück said, or `fetch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you should not use jQuery in a react app - if you want to approche the same ajax request with axios (https://github.com/axios/axios):

```js
componentDidMount(){

    axios.get(url, {
        params: { 
            api_key: api_key, 
            q: this.state.q 
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the logic inside a method, in this case put it inside the `do_search`. `this` will be different instance if you try to access it outside the instance method.. So write it like:

```
do_search(keyword) {
  url = url + "?" + $.param({ api_key, q: this.state.q });
  news = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET"
  })
    .done(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(err => {
      throw err;
    });
}
```

When you refer `this` inside the methods like `doSearch`, this points to the instance of `App` which were created by `<App />` somewhere in your program. So `state` is also available.

Note: Don't use Arrow functions when you pass a method as a props to any child components, rather bind it inside the constructor and use it..In this case write it like.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      q: "usa"
    };
    this.do_search = this.do_search.bind(this);
  }

  do_search(keyword) {
    url = url + "?" + $.param({ api_key, q: this.state.q });
    news = $
      .ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET"
      })
      .done(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .fail(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchComponent searchkeyword={this.do_search} />
        <ListViewComponent data={DATA} /> // I have deleted const DATA to reduce
        pasted code in SO.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this will not work beacause unbinded, you have to use "bind" or arrow functions to get the right scope

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Hmm.. Just saw it will work, as it is called inside the `() => {}` function.. `searchkeyword={keyword => {this.do_search(keyword);}}` .. No need to bind it in this case inside the constructor function. Although I don't like the `() => {}` as callback props.

Comment: Yes the problem in the code of the question is that the variable state is accessed before constructor, your code should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code in componentDidMount like this:

```js
componentDidMount(){
  const url = url + "?" + $.param({ api_key, q: this.state.q });
  const news = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET"
  })
  .done(result => {
      console.log(result);
  })
  .fail(err => {
      throw err;
  });
}
```